# ls with grep not working inside shell script

Tags: shell, grep, ls

I want my shell script to list all files in a directory but only show me the ones starting with e.g. a certain letter. Everything else if working fine and even the command `ls -t $1 | grep '^$2' | head -n 5` works inside the shell. But when I run the script this commandline doesn't do anything :(

```
if [ -d $1 ]
then echo "5 biggest files in $1:"
     ls -S $1 | head -n 5
     sleep 5
     echo "5 last modified files starting with '$2' in $1:"
     ls -t $1 | grep '^$2' | head -n 5
else
     if [ -a $1 ]
         then echo $1 is not a directory
         else echo $1 could not be found
     fi
fi
```

I also tried different variations of the line and it seems like the combination of ls and grep **inside the shell script** is causing the error.

Comment: change `'^$2'` to `"^$2"` and the string will be interpolated. But you may have to elsewhere defend against filenames having whitespace.

Comment: Well that was a quick solution, thanks!

Comment: @AnonPJ : Why don't you simply write `ls -t $2*`? As long as $2 consists only of letters, there is no need to grep. If there is a risk that the parameter also contains other characters, this make also break your _grep_ solution, depending on the type of characters.